# NEO4J Load csv not working

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I use the following Neo4J query to attempt to load from a .csv placed in the 'import' directory of the relevant database

```
load csv with headers from "file:///fb4.csv" as line with line
create (:Entry {name:"Co-ordinates", X:toInteger(line.`X`), Y:toInteger(`Y`), Z:toInteger(`Z`), rock_type:line.`GM fault block 4`})
```

The file 'fb4.csv' from which I load it from has the following first few lines:

```
# Exported from Leapfrog Geo - UTF-8 encoding
X,Y,Z,GM fault block 4
1492275,5215985,165,Enys Formation
1492285,5215985,165,Enys Formation
```

After waiting the 40 required seconds to run the query totally, usually I have 4.6 million co-ordinates with merely the 'name' property set - none of the others are set. i.e. None of the fields that are imported from fb4.csv are set, at all.

How does one sort this problem out properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load csv` statement does not process the first line as a comment, but interprets it as a header:

```
load csv with headers from "file:///fb4.csv" as line with line
return line
```

==>

```
{
  "# Exported from Leapfrog Geo - UTF-8 encoding": "X"
}
{
  "# Exported from Leapfrog Geo - UTF-8 encoding": "1492275"
}
{
  "# Exported from Leapfrog Geo - UTF-8 encoding": "1492285"
}
```

Remove the comment line from the csv-file.